# Servlet directory structure realization in Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

The project directory structure of a simple Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse [maps to the Web application archive (WAR) structure defined by Sun Microsystems](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fccwebprj.html), though the servlet structure defined by Sun Microsystems is clearly [a bit different](https://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-a-servlet-using-tomcat-server).

I just want to know that when I am creating only a single Servlet class inside the Dynamic Web project, how is the mapping done to the Servlet class file? I checked into **web.xml** and there was no corresponding `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` children and when I run the application, the URL looks something like

```
http://localhost:8080/firstServlet/Hello
```

where **firstServlet** is my project name and **Hello** is the servlet class.

1.How does it get to know about which class has to be run? I mean there's no `url-pattern` specified as **Hello** so why the URL is like that? If there's no `url-pattern`, shouldn't it just be `http://localhost:8080/firstServlet`?

2.Also, how is this project structure setting internally with the standard servlet project structure I have mentioned above?

Comment: check for any @WebServlet annotation in your code, you can also map Servlets and Filters thorugh those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that, you are using annotation configuration which does not need any mapping with web.xml

Your servlet url pattern would be something like below:

```
@WebServlet(name = "someThing", urlPatterns = {"/Hello"})
```

This new feature from Servlet 3.0 enables you to map your servlet `Hello` to your web App `firstServlet`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured if we remove the annotation and add the `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` children to web.xml with `url-pattern`=`\Hello`, it works the same way. 
What I don't understand is when I tried putting `url-pattern` as `/welcome`, it didn't work which is not the case the case [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-a-servlet-using-tomcat-server). As you'd see, the class name is `DemoServlet` but he uses`/welcome`; when I use anything apart from `/Hello`, it doesn't work which I don't understand as there I have already mentioned `servlet-class` as `Hello` in web.xml.

Comment: Url pattern can be any String, but the servlet name should be same as your servlet Class name. Do check the servlet name is `Hello` whereas. pattern is `/welcome`. Also, need to redeploy your web App.

Comment: I am so sorry! It actually works with any arbitrary string as long as the class name is fed right, I must've not refreshed it properly! Thank you.

Comment: Also, multiple mappings, that is, different url-patterns through web annotations and servlet-mappings in web.xml for a single servlet file also work resulting in multiple addresses to a single servlet.

Comment: A servlet can have mulitiple url-patterns, you can add mulitple patterns in web.xml or annotation configuration or combination of both. Usually, only one configuration should be used.